# Receive notification if automation resulted in audience volume greather than specific threshold

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio

I would like to know if there is a way to be notified in SFMC automation if result in audience greater than 100k and halt the automation so that we can throttle the volume over multiple days if necessary to avoid potential ISP blocking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the new verification actitivty feature just released in June could assist you here. CHeck out the release notes here which detail what the function does and how to use it.

http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/release_notes/june_2017_release/journey_builder/

Comment: Andrew is spot on here - this was just released, at least partially :)